exact paragraph number after extracting pdf content
I aim to extract precise paragraph numbers when extracting text from a PDF. My current approach involves removing table and image content along with their bounding box (bbox) values from the PDF before extracting text. However, even after implementing these steps, I'm encountering difficulties in obtaining the exact paragraph numbers.
I have tried with pdfminer to extract text excluding table and image content but not able to get exact paragraph number
